# Load form asynchronously

Tags: c#, winforms

My Winforms project has an mdi form as the main form and on form load, I'm also loading and maximizing a child form.

When running the app, one can see the child form displayed in its default size and then being maximized.

Is it possible to load this form asynchronously and display it when it's maximized?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you should be able to set the Form's `Visible` property to `false` so that it's not immediately visible. EDIT: note that you'll have to set this in the Form's constructor, after calling InitializeComponent(). It doesn't seem to be browseable in the Designer.

Comment: All interaction with the screen must happen on the main GUI thread, or you will get an `InvalidOperationException` with the message "Control control name accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on", oft referred to as a Cross-Thread Exception. You can do non-GUI work in the background but the `Show` must happen on the right thread. See here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.110).aspx